# Deep cloning an IOrderedQueryable object?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got an `IOrderedQueryable` collection of objects I'm pulling from a database and keeping in a `messages` variable.

When I want to do anything like this:

```
_lastMsg = messages.OrderByDescending(msg => msg.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

this seems to change the value of `messages`. I can't have this kind of behavior, so I want to clone the `messages` collection.

How would I go about doing that? Normally I would just add the `IClonable` interface into my class definition, but I don't think I can extend the built-in `IOrderedQueryable` class?

Comment: How does it change `messages`? LINQ methods are designed not to have side effects. I wouldn't start creating work-arounds for something that shouldn't happen in the first place, or maybe something you don't fully understand.

Comment: What actually gets changed, the messages collection, or the one item (object) that was returned?

Comment: An `IQueryable` is a representation of a query, *not* a list of objects. Executing it is guaranteed to have side-effects. If `messages` is indeed an `IOrderedQueryable` instead of an `IEnumerable` with the query results,  you have no objects, just a query that hasn't executed yet. Moreover, executing it multiple times will result in multiple query executions, that can easily return different results, if the underlying data has changed

Comment: How is `messages` assigned? Are you using LINQ to Entity/SQL/NHibernate, something else? How do you detect that there are changes in `messages` ?